# Unable to insert data into db via an Observable

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I have the following Observable where I am expecting some DB insertions to occur upon subscribing to it.
But nothing happens, no DB inserts and same time no errors either.

But If I directly subscribe to the method that does the DB calls, the DB insert occurs as expected.
How can I fix this such that the subscription to the Observable call below will perform the DB insert?

Please advice. Thanks.

This is the Observable where no DB insert occurs and no errors. I want to change this such that the DB insertion occurs when I subscribe to this Observable.

```
public Observable<KafkaConsumerRecord<String, RequestObj>> apply(KafkaConsumerRecords<String, RequestObj> records) {

    Observable.from(records.getDelegate().records().records("TOPIC_NAME"))
            .buffer(2)
            .map(this::convertToEventRequest)
            .doOnNext(this::handleEventInsertions)
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("Subscribed!"))
            .subscribe(); // purposely subscribing here itself to test 

    return null; // even if I return this observable and subscribe at the caller, same outcome. 
}
```

Just to test if the query works, if I were to directly subscribe to the method that does the insertion, it works as expected as follows.
Doing this in debug mode.

```
client.rxQueryWithParams(query, new JsonArray(params)).subscribe() // works
```

The following are references to see whats happening inside the convertToEventRequest and handleEventInsertions methods

```
private Map<String, List<?>> convertToEventRequest(Object records) {
    List<ConsumerRecord<String, RequestObj>> consumerRecords = (List<ConsumerRecord<String, RequestObj>>) records;

    List<AddEventRequest> addEventRequests = new ArrayList<>();
    List<UpdateEventRequest> updateEventRequests = new ArrayList<>();

    consumerRecords.forEach(record -> {
        String eventType = new String(record.headers().headers("type").iterator().next().value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        if("add".equals(eventType)) {
            AddEventRequest request = AddEventRequest.builder()
                    .count(Integer.parseInt(new String(record.headers().headers("count").iterator().next().value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                    .data(record.value())
                    .build();
            addEventRequests.add(request);
        } else {
            UpdateEventRequest request = UpdateEventRequest.builder()
                    .id(new String(record.headers().headers("id").iterator().next().value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .status(Integer.parseInt(new String(record.headers().headers("status").iterator().next().value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
                    .build();
            updateEventRequests.add(request);
        }
    });

    return new HashMap<String, List<?>>() {{
        put("add", addEventRequests);
        put("update", updateEventRequests);
    }};
}

private void handleEventInsertions(Object eventObject) {
    Map<String, List<?>> eventMap = (Map<String, List<?>>) eventObject;

    List<AddEventRequest> addEventRequests = (List<AddEventRequest>) eventMap.get("add");
    List<UpdateEventRequest> updateEventRequests = (List<UpdateEventRequest>) eventMap.get("update");

    if(addEventRequests != null && !addEventRequests.isEmpty()) {
        insertAddEvents(addEventRequests);
    }
    if(updateEventRequests != null && !updateEventRequests.isEmpty()) {
        insertUpdateEvents(updateEventRequests);
    }
}

private Single<ResultSet> insertAddEvents(List<AddEventRequest> requests) {
    AddEventRequest request = requests.get(0);
    List<Object> params = Arrays.asList(request.getCount(), request.getData());
    String query = "INSERT INTO mytable(count, data, creat_ts) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, current_timestamp)";
    return client.rxQueryWithParams(query, new JsonArray(params));
}

private Single<ResultSet> insertUpdateEvents(List<UpdateEventRequest> requests) {
    UpdateEventRequest request = requests.get(0);
    return client.rxQueryWithParams(
            "UPDATE mytable SET status=?, creat_ts=current_timestamp WHERE id=?",
            new JsonArray(Arrays.asList(request.getStatus(), request.getId())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to wrap it into `Observable.defer`?

```
Observable.defer(() -> Observable.from(records.getDelegate().records().records("TOPIC_NAME"))...
```

Comment: Wrapping it into defer as above makes no difference.